# Как поменять много url в 4000 html файлов?

Tags: html, txt

Есть абсолютно идентичных 4000 html файлов . В них есть фраза  qwerty   , как вместо qwerty заменить на имя файла?

Так как все файлы пронумерованы по порядку от 1 до 4000, то можно вместо qwerty вбить по порядку цифры в каждый файл:
1..2..3..4..5......4000

В данном скриншоте вместо qwerty нужно поставить 1601, в следующем файле нужно вместо qwerty поставить 1602 и так далее.
[image: скриншот]

Comment: вам статически надо внутри файлов сделать такую замену или динамически, чтобы определялось имя файла при выполнении html и подставлялось соответствующее значение?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы написал небольшой скрипт на nodejs.
Я писать его полностью сюда не буду, но попробую дать наводку

1. Получил все файлы из папки

   ```
    var files = fs.readdirSync(dir);
      for (var i in files){
         //тут получил бы имя файла и вызвал ф-ю для замены текста
      }
   ```
2. Написал ф-ю для замены текста

   ```
       fs.readFile(someFile, 'utf8', function (err,data) {
          if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
          }
          var result = data.replace(/string to be replaced/g, 'replacement');        
          fs.writeFile(someFile, result, 'utf8', function (err) {
             if (err) return console.log(err);
          });
        });
   ```

Ну или можно код ф-ии для замены прям в цикл вставить.
Ну как-то так.

Answer (score 0):

Для примера вот так это можно сделать на питоне. Соответственно необходимо заменить путь до файлов в open (вместо D:\ на свой).
В каждом файле от 1.html до 3999.html будут заменены все слова qwerty на номер файла. Если это файл 20.html и qwerty-12 то будет 20-12.
Только предварительно сохраните ваши файлы, т.к решение я не проверял.

```
 for i in range(1,4000):
    
        try:
            with open('D:\\'+str(i)+'.html', 'r') as f:
                text = f.read()
    
            text = text.replace('qwerty',str(i))
    
            with open('D:\\'+str(i)+'.html', 'w') as f:
                f.write(text)
        except:
            print ("Файл не существует")
```

Comment: Странно, почему то пишет что файл не существует . скриншот https://prnt.sc/v791ma

Comment: @Михаил, попробуйте путь не через / а через \\, например: C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\

Comment: я так сразу попробовал, потому что питон ругался. 

С этим кодом то же самое выдаёт: https://prnt.sc/v7dnb9

Код:

`for i in range(1551,1571):
    

 try:


with open('C:\\Users\\mik777em\\Downloads\\ya\\hook\\new\\test\\1\\'+str(i)+'.html', 'r') as f:


text = f.read()


    
text = text.replace('qwerty',str(i))
    


with open('C:\\Users\\mik777em\\Downloads\\ya\\hook\\new\\test\\1\\'+str(i)+'.html', 'w') as f:



f.write(text)
except:
print ("file ne syshestvuet") `

Comment: Попробовал у себя - работает. У вас какая операционка?

Comment: операционка windows 10.

Запускаю в  IDLE (Python 3.8 32-bit)

Comment: Можно попробовать убрать try и except чтобы посмотреть что за ошибка происходит. И попробуйте ещё запустить скрипт через cmd  "python 1.py".